# Push / Perform segue from Swift VC to Objective-C VC not working

Tags: objective-c, swift, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard, bridging-header

My project was developed in Swift. We want to add one feature which was already implemented in Objective-C. When I try to push from my Swift VC to that Objective-C VC then, I received below warning and push not successful.

I confirmed that bridging header and other build settings has been configured perfectly.

> I have 2 ObjC VC files. One VC is completely designed in code so there is no problem to push to that VC. But, in other is designed in segue that i can't push/show from my Swift VC.

**Using Navigation Push:**

`let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "XXXViewController") as? XXXViewController // vc always returns nil
if let vc = vc {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) // can't compile because of vc is nil
        }`

**Warning:**

> Unknown class _TtC12ProjectName36XXXViewController in Interface Builder file.

**Using Segue:**

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeToXXXVc", sender: self)`

**Error:**

> Unknown class _TtC12ProjectName36XXXViewController in Interface Builder file.
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< UIViewController 0x10132ef60 > setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key yyyLabel.

*// yyyLabel - One of outlet of Objective-C Vc.*

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem is basically on the interface builder.

If the error is "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key yyyLabel." then it's the source "yyyLabel" on you code deleted on the xib/storyboard but you access it on your class.

Check again your class in xib/storyboard, check the outlets don't have any warning.

Comment: Everything is connected properly. No issues in outlet connection, class and Module name, Storyboard ID name.

Comment: Did you try to push from Swift VC to ObjC Vc before?

Comment: I use combined swiftVC and objcVC for years, based on your error it is the problem in the yyylabel, try check the yyylabel in you code and your layout.
there is no problem pushing swiftvc and objcvc.

As long it not using swiftUI *need fully swift code currently

Comment: maybe you forget adding storyboardID for that class in the storyboard mohd

Comment: I remove the html tag interpretation of the error. The VC is considered as a UIViewController by default (missing module ?), not related to linked (for now) Outlet issue.

Comment: Have you creating bridging module for swift to objc? otherwise the objc class won't detected in the swift porhect

Comment: Whatever you spot the points are everything is configured correctly and completely.

Comment: Actually, yyyLabel is first outlet declared in that class. If its any other outlet declared at first also causing same issue.

Comment: Is the story return nil?
Have you tried put the vc in the nib?